# GStringImpl in groovy File() constructor

Tags: string, file-io, groovy

I am running into a bit of a strange error here when creating a new file object with a `GStringImpl`.  If I create a new File (and then list files in that path) with a `GStringImpl`, I get an empty array, and no error, however if I just a normal string, I get a list of files...  While that makes sense in a way I would think that there would be an error somewhere.

Example:

```
def thisIsAListOfFiles = new File("/absolute/fs/mount/point").listFiles()

def gString = "${StaticClass.propertyStringThatIsAnAbsoluteFilePath}"
def notAListOfFiles = new File(gString).listFiles()
```

Any thoughts on what is going on here?  Is this the expected behavior?

More info:

- Groovy Version: 2.1.3
- Grails version: 2.2.2 (this is within a grails app of course)
- Java version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9)

I start out with a properties file with a bunch of properties like this

```
com.mycompany.property = "/absolute/directory/path"
```

Because I cant easily inject `grailsApplication` into non grails classes (anything in `/src/groovy` for instance) I inject `grailsApplication` into bootstrap, and use groovy config slurper to read the properties file from the classpath and set then as static string values in a groovy class Config.groovy.  That groovy class then has the static variables of all of the properties I need anywhere within the application.

Note: this is not an issue reading the properties files, or anything along those lines.  I log the `Config.filePathProperty` right before the `new File(var).listFiles()` occurs and that value is set properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your static path is set incorrectly.  I ran the following code as a test:

```
String path = '/etc/'

print "String ($path): "
println(new File(path).listFiles().size())

def gpath = "${path}"

print "GString ($gpath): "
println(new File(gpath).listFiles().size())

class Foo {
    static String path = '/etc/'
}

print "GString static ($Foo.path): "
println(new File("${Foo.path}").listFiles().size())
```

And got this result (obviously your file count will vary):

```
String (/etc/): 122
GString (/etc/): 122
GString static (/etc/): 122
```

The only time I saw a `null` result was when the path was invalid, for example:

```
assert new File("does-not-exist").listFiles() == null
```

One thing you could do would be to eliminate the GString, which is unnecessary in your example:

```
def notAListOfFiles = new File(StaticClass.propertyStringThatIsAnAbsoluteFilePath).listFiles()
```

But I'm sure you'll find a typo in the variable or file path, or another similar issue.

Comment: Sorry about the long reply.  You were correct, and I was too tired and too undercafinated to think properly.  I was setting the path "correctly" in that it was the right absolute path, but the way I was using java properties was wrong.  It is `key=value` NOT `key="quoted values are wrong..."`.  So thank you.  The log.info's and println's showed this of course, but I just completely missed that because I tend to quote some var's some times in log statements...